# Parsing large log file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a log file with 1,001,623 lines formatted as such:

```
[02/Jan/2012:09:07:32] "GET /click?id=162&prod=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
```

Each separated by a new line

I used regular expressions to loop over it and extract the information i need (date,id, product)

```
for txt in logfile:
    m = rg.search(txt)
    if m:
        l1=m.group(1)
        l2=m.group(2)
        l3=m.group(3)
        dt=dt.append(pd.Series([l1]))
        art=art.append(pd.Series([l2]))
        usr=usr.append(pd.Series([l3]))
```

This works fine in testing where I only used a small sample but when I used the entire set its been running for 12 hours and not showing any progress. I will then create a dataframe to do some analytics. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit:

This is how I open the log file.

```
logfile = open("data/access.log", "r")
```

The regex

```
re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re2='((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])'  # DDMMMYYYY 1
re3='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re4='\\d+'  # Uninteresting: int
re5='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re6='\\d+'  # Uninteresting: int
re7='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re8='\\d+'  # Uninteresting: int
re9='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re10='(\\d+)'   # Integer Number 1
re11='.*?'  # Non-greedy match on filler
re12='(\\d+)'   # Integer Number 2

rg =  re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
```

Comment: Can you please add how you open the file (variable txt)?

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? How did you assign `logfile` and what is your regex?

Comment: Added the information, thank you!

Comment: It may be taking a long time because I don't think you are reading the file line by line. You should be doing `for txt in logfile.readlines():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas`. First strip `[]` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Then parse `id` and `prod` and last merge all together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""[02/Jan/2012:09:07:32] "GET /click?id=162&prod=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
[02/Jan/2012:09:07:32] "GET /click?id=162&prod=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
[02/Jan/2012:09:07:32] "GET /click?id=162&prod=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
[02/Jan/2012:09:07:32] "GET /click?id=162&prod=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352
[02/Jan/2012:09:07:32] "GET /click?id=162&prod=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352"""

#change io.StringIO(temp) to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s*", engine='python', header=None, 
                                    names=['date','get','data','http','no1','no2'])

#format - http://strftime.org/
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.strip('[]'), format="%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

#split Dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('=') for x in df['data'].tolist() ], columns=['c','id','prod'])

#split Dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('&') for x in df1['id'].tolist() ], columns=['id', 'no3'])
```

```
print df

                 date   get                     data       http  no1   no2
0 2012-01-02 09:07:32  "GET  /click?id=162&prod=5475  HTTP/1.1"  200  4352
1 2012-01-02 09:07:32  "GET  /click?id=162&prod=5475  HTTP/1.1"  200  4352
2 2012-01-02 09:07:32  "GET  /click?id=162&prod=5475  HTTP/1.1"  200  4352
3 2012-01-02 09:07:32  "GET  /click?id=162&prod=5475  HTTP/1.1"  200  4352
4 2012-01-02 09:07:32  "GET  /click?id=162&prod=5475  HTTP/1.1"  200  4352
print df1

           c        id  prod
0  /click?id  162&prod  5475
1  /click?id  162&prod  5475
2  /click?id  162&prod  5475
3  /click?id  162&prod  5475
4  /click?id  162&prod  5475
print df2

    id   no3
0  162  prod
1  162  prod
2  162  prod
3  162  prod
4  162  prod

df = pd.concat([df['date'], df1['prod'], df2['id']], axis=1)
```

```
print df

                 date  prod   id
0 2012-01-02 09:07:32  5475  162
1 2012-01-02 09:07:32  5475  162
2 2012-01-02 09:07:32  5475  162
3 2012-01-02 09:07:32  5475  162
4 2012-01-02 09:07:32  5475  162
```

Comment: I clearly still know nothing, that was beautiful! Thank you.